# Why does the IR reciver gives diffrent value everytime I try to break a for loop - when new value is recived, Arduino ide?

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I am new to Arduino programming and was trying to make an IR-controlled WS2812 led strip light, everything works fine apart from when I try to stop the for-loop when my IR receiver gets a new decoded value. It does get the job done but the received values are different every time. when I tested the same controller with a simple IR receiver program everything worked fine.

```
switch(value){
         case 16720095:
          delay (200); 
          irrecv.resume();
          for (int i = 0; i <= 182; i++) {
           leds[i] = CRGB (0,0,0);
           FastLED.show();
             if (irrecv.decode(&results))
             {
               value = results.value;     
               Serial.println(value);
               break;
              }
             delay(40);
            }
          } 
         }
```

and the serial outputs:
first time:

> 16720095
>
> -1572362453

second time:

> 16720095
>
> -1406992986

third time:

> 16720095
>
> 811035822

Comment: It would be helpful if you included a distilled version of your code that highlights the issue. As your question stands, it is difficult to understand what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the part of the code that the problem occurs in.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to call "irrecv.resume()" within the  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) block in order to tell the driver to keep looking for signals. The second values you are getting are garbage because you are asking it to provide data it hasn't received/ prepared.

Comment: Thanks I will try

Comment: In general, you'll want to distill down your question more to focus on what exactly you are having problem in. This means need to create a self-contained (someone could run your code on their device) minimum size example that shows the problem you are having. This process of distilling down questions not only helps direct those that might answer, it also shows you have put sufficient work into solving your own problem and can show to respondents that you have put forth effort yourself (since you are asking others to put in work solving your problem it only makes sense).